# Убрать дубликаты поиска по строке связанной таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть 2 связанные таблицы mysql. В одной таблице бренды, а во второй модели. На вход мы получаем текст, в котором нужно найти совпадение по моделям и отправить в список. Сам поиск работает, там вопросов нет. Вопрос в другом. Есть случаи когда в тексте указана модель, но не указан бренд. Так вот нужно что бы по модели определялся бренд и отправлялся в список с брендами. И тоже как все работает, но есть проблема, так как у бренда может быть много разных моделей, то в список конечно же отправляются дубликаты брендов.

Кто знает, как реализовать на PHP удаление дубликатов? Подскажите идею или где об этом можно почитать. Вроде бы близок к решению, но все-равно не выходит.

Код:

```
<?php
$html = '<div id="one">
        <select id="first">
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
        <select id="second">
        </select>
        </div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$result_one = get_model();
$string = "audi BMW BMW Ford Ford Ford Ford Ford A6 'A5' mokka mokka.";
if($result_one == true){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_one)){
        $pattern = "/\b" . $row["name_model"] . "\b/i";
        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches)){
            for ($i=0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++){
                $count = count($matches[0]);
                $result = $matches[0][$i];
                $result_id = $row["brand_id"];
            }//echo $count;

            $item = $dom->getElementById('first');
            $opt = $item->appendChild($dom->createElement("option", $result));

            $query  = "SELECT * ";
            $query .= "FROM brands ";
            $query .= "WHERE brand_id = $result_id ";
            $result_match = mysqli_query($link, $query);

            $result_two = $result_match;
            var_dump($result_two);
            if($result_two == true) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_two)){
                    $res = $row["brand_name"];

                    $item_2 = $dom->getElementById('second');
                    $opt = $item_2->appendChild($dom->createElement("option", $res));
                }

            }
        }

    }


} 
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: `$string = implode(' ', array_unique(explode(' ', $string)));`

Comment: вы бы написали конкретную задачу, что есть на входе, и что надо на выходе. Если надо удалить дубликаты из строки, то спросите именно об этом, не надо писать про то как у вас поиск работает и т.п. не относящееся к делу

Comment: На входе строка, где есть 4 модели, по поиску они находятся и выводятся в список. Мне нужно что бы по найденным моделям вставило из базы бренды этих моделей. И принципе на ходит и вставляет в другой список. Но на выходе у нас A6, A5, mokka, mokka. На выходе выдает Audi, Audi, Opel. Мне нужно что бы Audi был один раз. С конвертацией  я уже игрался. Проблема в том что после поиска каждое совпадение кидает в отдельный массив. Если конвертировать, то строки будут как три строки. Если же извлечь индексы брендов, которые подставляются в новый запрос, для определения брендов, будут значения 1, 1, 6.

Comment: Повторения идут на этапе сравнения, буду копать там, может найду что не так там. Ибо данные для второго запроса формируются там. Пойду поколупаю спеку, может найду решение как иначе вывести данные.